# NoClassDefFoundError while using DropBox Core API

Tags: java, json, dropbox-api

I have copy pasted the following code from the official DropBox API Tutorials. The aim of this code is to upload a text file. I am using the `DropBox-core-sdk-3.0.3.jar` . But i am getting

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonParseException
    at com.dropbox.core.DbxHost.<clinit>(DbxHost.java:114)
    at com.dropbox.core.v2.DbxClientV2.<init>(DbxClientV2.java:31)
    at dropboxtest.Main.main(Main.java:24)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

Now the solution to this maybe, adding `jackson-annotations.jar` to the class path but, I have tried this and this does not seem to work,and I get the same Exception and I have some unused Imports

Here is the code:

```
package dropboxtest;

import com.dropbox.core.DbxException;
import com.dropbox.core.DbxRequestConfig;
import com.dropbox.core.v2.DbxClientV2;
import com.dropbox.core.v2.files.FileMetadata;
import com.dropbox.core.v2.files.ListFolderResult;
import com.dropbox.core.v2.files.Metadata;
import com.dropbox.core.v2.users.FullAccount;

import java.util.List;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {

    private static final String ACCESS_TOKEN = "XXXXXX";

    public static void main(String args[]) throws DbxException, IOException {
        // Create Dropbox client
        DbxRequestConfig config = new DbxRequestConfig("dropbox/java-tutorial", "en_US");
        DbxClientV2 client = new DbxClientV2(config, ACCESS_TOKEN);

        // Get current account info
        FullAccount account = client.users().getCurrentAccount();
        System.out.println(account.getName().getDisplayName());

        // Get files and folder metadata from Dropbox root directory
        ListFolderResult result = client.files().listFolder("");
        while (true) {
            for (Metadata metadata : result.getEntries()) {
                System.out.println(metadata.getPathLower());
            }

            if (!result.getHasMore()) {
                break;
            }

            result = client.files().listFolderContinue(result.getCursor());
        }

        // Upload "test.txt" to Dropbox
        try (InputStream in = new FileInputStream("test.txt")) {
            FileMetadata metadata = client.files().uploadBuilder("/test.txt")
                    .uploadAndFinish(in);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do not depends on the IDE and run it yourself. Check the output JAR file for sure about the exsitance of `jackson-annotation-x.x.x.jar` and make sure the class is absolutely there. Please let me know if all seems correct. BTW, you should paste more details about the way you run your application and the classpaths of your application. Otherwise, it's hard to see what's going wrong.

Comment: You pointed to the right direction. I actually had to use `jackson-core-2.xx` not `jackson-annotation-xx.xx.`  DropBox forgot to mention it in their documentation, or I am a real newbie. I will answer my question now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short Answer: Use [`jackson-core-x.x.x`](http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.9.0.pr3/jackson-core-2.9.0.pr3.jar) instead of `jackson-annotation-xxx`

Long Answer:As pointed out by Gemini Keith, the problem was my classpath. The `dropbox-core-sdk-3.0.3.jar` actually needs another Library it being `jackson-core-2.6.1`. Though, this is nowhere mentioned in the official Documentation by DropBox for API v2. But on looking at the Documentation for API v1 by DropBox, and on reading the line

> The necessary JAR files are in the "lib/" folder.

I proceeded to download the API v1 Sample Codes. and then added `jackson-core-x.x.x` from the lib folder to my Current classpath and VIOLA everything was working fine.

Comment: i am add jackson-core-2.6.1, and my issue solved, thanks